# Converting Str Column to Int Not Working in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code to load data

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("Salary-Data.csv")
data["Income"] = data["Income"].str.strip()
#data["Income"] = data["Income"].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
#data["Income"] = data["Income"].astype(int)
data
```

This produces the following error:

> ~/miniconda3/envs/scientific-base/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx
> in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe()
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '16\xa0638'

The first value in the `Income` column is `16 638` (with a space).

If I comment out the erroring line and inspect the dataframe, the values in `Income` column still contain spaces.

What is going on? How can I make this column into one of valid integers or floats?

Answer (score 1):

Change `strip` to `replace`

```
data["Income"] = data["Income"].str.replace(' ','')
```

Comment: I have actually tried that. The same exact thing persists. Makes me wonder if there is some weird symbol in there instead of a white space.

Comment: I copied the symbol directly from the CSV and pasted as the argument to `replace`. It worked!

Comment: @MadPhysicist  or you can use regex, see solution below

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do it, i.e., to replace out all non-digit characters

```
df['income'].replace(r'\D','',regex=True)
```

to keep the decimal as part of the number

```
df['income'].replace(r'[^0-9,\.]','',regex=True)
```